# HTML Form Doesn't Send Data through AJAX Post

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a DataTable that uses AJAX to pull from 8 different SharePoint lists, and organizes them based on there Program attribute, then child row is organized by the Deliverable attribute, followed by the grandchild rows which is the remaining information about the "Deliverable". Everything about that aspect works perfectly for my DataTable.

However, I need to be able to write back information to this DataTable, so the easiest route I thought to take would to be a HTML form read the input, then post it to the corresponding SharePoint list based on its "Program" attribute. I have the form built under the DataTable and I cannot figure out how to get it to send to the SharePoint list. I am currently only using only one Program just to see if it works and I am unsuccessful. I tried to console.log() a few things and nothing showed up.

Here is a picture of my table and form.
[image]

Here is my code:

```js
function loadData() { //Initializing the AJAX Request function to load in the external list data from different subsites
    //create an array of urls to run through the ajax request instead of having to do multiple AJAX Requests
    var urls = [baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AMMO Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes", 
    "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Dar-Q Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes", 
    "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WTBn Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ODMultiDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('OEDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AHRDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SRCDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"];
    
    for (i=0; i < urls.length; i++) { //for loop to run through the AJAX until all URLs have been reached
      $.ajax({
        url: urls[i],
        'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
        success: function (data) { // success function which will then execute "GETTING" the data to post it to a object array (data.value)
          data = data;
          var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
          table.rows.add( data.value ).draw();
        }
      }); 
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var collapsedGroups = {}; 
    var top = '';
    var parent = '';
    
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
  "pageLength": 100,
    "columns": [
      { "data": null, "defaultContent": "" },
      { "data": "Program", visible: false },
      { "data": "Deliverable", visible: false },
      { "data": "To" },
      { "data": "Date" },
      { "data": "Approved" },
      { "data": "Notes" }
    ],
    
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-10'f><'col-sm-12 col-md-2'B>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
     buttons: [{
      extend: 'collection',
      className: "btn-dark",
      text: 'Export or Update Table',
      buttons:
      [{
      extend: "excel", className: "btn-dark"
    },
      {
      extend: "pdf", className: "btn-dark"
    },
       {
      extend: "print", className: "btn-dark"   
    },
    {
    text: 'Update Table',
    action: function (e, dt, node, config){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    },
      ],
    }],
    order: [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc'] ],   
    rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: [
            'Program',
            'Deliverable'
            ],
            startRender: function (rows,group,level){
                var all;
                if (level === 0) {
                    top = group;
                    all = group;
                } else if (level === 1) {
                    parent = top + group; 
                    all = parent; 
                    // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                    if (!collapsedGroups[top]) {
                        return;
                    }                   
                } else {
                    // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                    if (!collapsedGroups[parent]) {
                        return;
                    } 
                    all = top + parent + group;
                }

                var collapsed = !collapsedGroups[all];
                console.log('collapsed:', collapsed);
              
              rows.nodes().each(function(r) {
                r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
              });
              //Add category name to the <tr>.
              return $('<tr/>')
                .append('<td colspan="8">' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
                .attr('data-name', all)
                .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
                
            
            }
            
        }
  } );
    
 loadData();

 $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr.dtrg-start', function () {
        var name = $(this).data('name');
        collapsedGroups[name] = !collapsedGroups[name];
        table.draw(false);
    });   

    
} );
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn").click(function(e){
        var jsonData = {};
        
    var formData = $("#myform").serializeArray();
    // console.log(formData);
    
    $.each(formData, function() {
            if (jsonData[this.name]) {
            if (!jsonData[this.name].push) {
                jsonData[this.name] = [jsonData[this.name]];
            }
            jsonData[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            jsonData[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
            
        
    });
    console.log(jsonData);
        $.ajax({  
                async: true, // Async by default is set to “true” load the script asynchronously  
                // URL to post data into sharepoint list  or your own url
                 url: baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AMMO Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes",
                method: "POST", //Specifies the operation to create the list item  
                data: JSON.stringify({  
                    '__metadata': {  
                        'type': 'SP.Data.AMMO_x0020_DeliverablesListItem' // it defines the ListEnitityTypeName  
                    },  
                //Pass the parameters
                    'Program': $("#dProgram").val(),  
                    'Deliverable':$("#dDeliverable").val(),  
                    'To': $("#dTo").val(),  
                    'Date': $("#dDate").val(),  
                    'Approved': $("#dApproved").val(),  
                    'Notes': $("#dNotes").val()            
                }),  
                headers: {  
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the Data format   
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the content type as JSON  
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() //It gets the digest value   
                },  
                success: function(data) {  
                    swal("Item created successfully", "success"); // Used sweet alert for success message  
                },  
                error: function(error) {  
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
        
                }  
        
            })  
        });
    });
```

```css
#myform {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:250px;
    padding:14px;
    align: center;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
}
label {
    width: 10em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.submit {
    float:right;
}

fieldset {
    background:#EBF4FB none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border:2px solid #B7DDF2;
    width: 450px;
}

legend {
    color: #fff;
    background: #80D3E2;
    border: 1px solid #781351;
    padding: 2px 6px
    text-align: center;
}
.elements {
    padding:10px;
}
p {
    border-bottom:1px solid #B7DDF2;
    color:#666666;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
span {
    color:#666666;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    
}
.btn{
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #B7DDF2;
  
}
.modal-dialog-centered {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-align:center;
  -ms-flex-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  min-height:calc(100% - (.5rem * 2));
}
.btn:hover{
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

div.container {
    min-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
    font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.dt-button-collection {
    position: static;
}
```

```html
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.2/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.2/css/rowGroup.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<link rel ="stylsheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
  <div class ="heading">
  <h1 class="center"><strong>Deliverables</strong></h1>
  </div>
<div class ="container">
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Program</th>
      <th>Deliverable</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Approved</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update DataTable</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
          
      <form id="myform" type="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend align="center">Update Datatable</legend>
    <p>Please fill out the shown fields to add data to the DataTable</p>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="program">Program :</label>
       <select name = "program" id = "dProgram">
            <option value = "AHR">AHR</option>
            <option value = "AMMO">AMMO</option>
            <option value = "DAR-Q">DAR-Q</option>
            <option value = "Doctrine Development">Doctrine Development</option>
            <option value = "Operational Energy">Operational Energy</option>
            <option value = "Ordnance Multimedia">Ordnance Multimedia</option>
            <option value = "SRC Handbook">SRC Handbook</option>
            <option value = "WTBn">WTBn</option>
         </select>
    </div>
     <div class="elements">
      <label for="Deliverable">Deliverable :</label>
      <select name="Deliverable" id="dDeliverable">
              <option value = "Meeting Minutes">Meeting Minutes</option>
            <option value = "Monthly Status Report (MSR)">Monthly Status Report (MSR)</option>
            </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="To"> To:</label>
      <input type="text" align= "center" id="dTo" name="to" placeholder="example@example.com">
    </div>      
    <div class="elements">
    <label for="Date">Date: </label>
      <input type="date" align= "center" id="dDate" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"> 
</div>  
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="Approved">Approved :</label>
      <select name="Approved" id="dApproved">
              <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value = "No">No</option></select>
</div>
      
      <div class="elements">
      <label for="Notes"> Notes :</label>
      <input type="text" align= "left" id="dNotes" name="notes" placeholder="Please provide notes">
   </div>
    
      <div class="submit">
       <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" name="btn-submit" class="btn-submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>    
          
          
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Are you wanting to send the formData to your URL1 via `$.ajax`

Comment: Yes through a post

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var baseUrl = "http://WebAppURL"
function loadData() { //Initializing the AJAX Request function to load in the external list data from different subsites
    //create an array of urls to run through the ajax request instead of having to do multiple AJAX Requests
    var urls = [baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AMMO Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes", 
    baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Dar-Q Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes", 
    baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WTBn Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ODMultiDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('OEDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AHRDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
    baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SRCDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"];
    
    for (i=0; i < urls.length; i++) { //for loop to run through the AJAX until all URLs have been reached
      $.ajax({
        url: urls[i],
        'headers': { 'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata' },
        success: function (data) { 
          console.log(data);
          if(data.d != null && data.d != undefined && data.d.results.length> 0){
              var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
              table.rows.add(data.d.results).draw();
          }
        }
      }); 
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var collapsedGroups = {}; 
    var top = '';
    var parent = '';
    
  var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
  "pageLength": 100,
    "columns": [
      { "data": null, "defaultContent": "" },
      { "data": "Program", visible: false },
      { "data": "Deliverable", visible: false },
      { "data": "To" },
      { "data": "Date" },
      { "data": "Approved" },
      { "data": "Notes" }
    ],
    
    dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-10'f><'col-sm-12 col-md-2'B>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
"<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
     buttons: [{
      extend: 'collection',
      className: "btn-dark",
      text: 'Export or Update Table',
      buttons:
      [{
      extend: "excel", className: "btn-dark"
    },
      {
      extend: "pdf", className: "btn-dark"
    },
       {
      extend: "print", className: "btn-dark"   
    },
    {
    text: 'Update Table',
    action: function (e, dt, node, config){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    },
      ],
    }],
    order: [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc'] ],   
    rowGroup: {
            dataSrc: [
            'Program',
            'Deliverable'
            ],
            startRender: function (rows,group,level){
                var all;
                if (level === 0) {
                    top = group;
                    all = group;
                } else if (level === 1) {
                    parent = top + group; 
                    all = parent; 
                    // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                    if (!collapsedGroups[top]) {
                        return;
                    }                   
                } else {
                    // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                    if (!collapsedGroups[parent]) {
                        return;
                    } 
                    all = top + parent + group;
                }

                var collapsed = !collapsedGroups[all];
                console.log('collapsed:', collapsed);
              
              rows.nodes().each(function(r) {
                r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
              });
              //Add category name to the <tr>.
              return $('<tr/>')
                .append('<td colspan="8">' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
                .attr('data-name', all)
                .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
                
            
            }
            
        }
  } );
    
    loadData();
    
    $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr.dtrg-start', function () {
        var name = $(this).data('name');
        collapsedGroups[name] = !collapsedGroups[name];
        table.draw(false);
    });   
    
    
    $("#btn").click(function(e){
        var jsonData = {};        
        var formData = $("#myform").serializeArray();
        $.each(formData, function() {
                if (jsonData[this.name]) {
                if (!jsonData[this.name].push) {
                    jsonData[this.name] = [jsonData[this.name]];
                }
                jsonData[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                jsonData[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }   
        });
        console.log(jsonData);
        $.ajax({  
                async: true, // Async by default is set to “true” load the script asynchronously  
                // URL to post data into sharepoint list  or your own url
                 url: baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AMMO Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes",
                method: "POST", //Specifies the operation to create the list item  
                data: JSON.stringify({  
                    '__metadata': {  
                        'type': 'SP.Data.AMMO_x0020_DeliverablesListItem' // it defines the ListEnitityTypeName  
                    },  
                //Pass the parameters
                    'Program': $("#dProgram").val(),  
                    'Deliverable':$("#dDeliverable").val(),  
                    'To': $("#dTo").val(),  
                    'Date': $("#dDate").val(),  
                    'Approved': $("#dApproved").val(),  
                    'Notes': $("#dNotes").val()            
                }),  
                headers: {  
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the Data format   
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the content type as JSON  
                    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() //It gets the digest value   
                },  
                success: function(data) {  
                    alert("Item created successfully", "success"); 
                },  
                error: function(error) {  
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
        
                }  
        
            })  
        });
    });
```

```css
#myform {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:250px;
    padding:14px;
    align: center;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
}
label {
    width: 10em;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.submit {
    float:right;
}

fieldset {
    background:#EBF4FB none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border:2px solid #B7DDF2;
    width: 450px;
}

legend {
    color: #fff;
    background: #80D3E2;
    border: 1px solid #781351;
    padding: 2px 6px
    text-align: center;
}
.elements {
    padding:10px;
}
p {
    border-bottom:1px solid #B7DDF2;
    color:#666666;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
span {
    color:#666666;
    font-size:12px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    
}
.btn{
  padding: 4px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333333;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #B7DDF2;
  
}
.modal-dialog-centered {
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -webkit-box-align:center;
  -ms-flex-align:center;
  align-items:center;
  min-height:calc(100% - (.5rem * 2));
}
.btn:hover{
  color: #333333;
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

div.container {
    min-width: 980px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.header {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
    font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
div.dt-button-collection {
    position: static;
}
```

```html
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.2/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.2/css/rowGroup.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<link rel ="stylsheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
  <div class ="heading">
  <h1 class="center"><strong>Deliverables</strong></h1>
  </div>
<div class ="container">
<table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Program</th>
      <th>Deliverable</th>
      <th>To</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Approved</th>
      <th>Notes</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update DataTable</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        
          
      <form id="myform" type="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend align="center">Update Datatable</legend>
    <p>Please fill out the shown fields to add data to the DataTable</p>
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="program">Program :</label>
       <select name = "program" id = "dProgram">
            <option value = "AHR">AHR</option>
            <option value = "AMMO">AMMO</option>
            <option value = "DAR-Q">DAR-Q</option>
            <option value = "Doctrine Development">Doctrine Development</option>
            <option value = "Operational Energy">Operational Energy</option>
            <option value = "Ordnance Multimedia">Ordnance Multimedia</option>
            <option value = "SRC Handbook">SRC Handbook</option>
            <option value = "WTBn">WTBn</option>
         </select>
    </div>
     <div class="elements">
      <label for="Deliverable">Deliverable :</label>
      <select name="Deliverable" id="dDeliverable">
              <option value = "Meeting Minutes">Meeting Minutes</option>
            <option value = "Monthly Status Report (MSR)">Monthly Status Report (MSR)</option>
            </select>
    </div>  
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="To"> To:</label>
      <input type="text" align= "center" id="dTo" name="to" placeholder="example@example.com">
    </div>      
    <div class="elements">
    <label for="Date">Date: </label>
      <input type="date" align= "center" id="dDate" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"> 
</div>  
    <div class="elements">
      <label for="Approved">Approved :</label>
      <select name="Approved" id="dApproved">
              <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
        <option value = "No">No</option></select>
</div>
      
      <div class="elements">
      <label for="Notes"> Notes :</label>
      <input type="text" align= "left" id="dNotes" name="notes" placeholder="Please provide notes">
   </div>
    
      <div class="submit">
       <input type="submit" id="btn-submit" name="btn-submit" class="btn-submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>    
          
          
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Your Snippit contains error/warnings as following:

1. URL array binding which is string break on array child.
2. Undefined object used to bind, SharePoint Rest API data parameter in
   Success method data.value is used while REST API returns JSON results as data.d.results.
3. Multiple document ready
4. baseUrl variable is not defined

Rest of all is good now but needs more code optimization.
Set baseUrl = "http://webappurl"; with your server/webappurl and try this snippit.

Try this snippit, Hope this can help you now.

Comment: Check my most recent post

Comment: The object arrays show up in the console... but do not populate the datatable.

Comment: Can you paste a screenshot of that? What it prints in console?

Comment: Go to chat so I can send in there

Comment: Hey, if youre available check out the chat.

Comment: I was away I am back now

Comment: Hello, I am back.

Comment: If you are able to join the chat, I may have found something helpful

Comment: I have a meeting. I can join you back after 90minutes

Comment: Unfortunately its still going on.

Comment: hey are you free?

Answer (score -1):

So i made Test in my environment SP-OnPrem 2013 and using a Script Editor webpart.
Here is the result. I made two list with Deliverables and saved this in Test1Deliverable.
[image]

[image]
Oh Gosh, I thought it was oblivious that you can bind variables from input field values to insert them in SP list but you are assigning them as the name of the field in input html. so you need to replace this section of script

```
            'Program': program,  
            'Deliverable': deliverable,  
            'To': to,  
            'Date': date,  
            'Approved': approved,  
            'Notes': notes

  Replace with
             'Program': $("#dProgram").val(),  
            'Deliverable':$("#dDeliverable").val(),  
            'To': $("#dTo").val(),  
            'Date': $("#dDate").val(),  
            'Approved': $("#dApproved").val(),  
            'Notes': $("#dNotes").val()
```

**Note: I gave Id to all the input and select elements and using their value to POST them into SP. After submit , just refresh the page or call loadData() again and in my case  Notes1 and Date1 columns used.**

In Case of My Script Editor Code:

```
        <style type="text/css">
            #myform {
                margin:0 auto;
                width:250px;
                padding:14px;
                align: center;
            }

            label {
                width: 10em;
                float: left;
                margin-right: 0.5em;
                display: block;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
            .submit {
                float:right;
            }

            fieldset {
                background:#EBF4FB none repeat scroll 0 0;
                border:2px solid #B7DDF2;
                width: 450px;
            }

            legend {
                color: #fff;
                background: #80D3E2;
                border: 1px solid #781351;
                padding: 2px 6px
                text-align: center;
            }
            .elements {
                padding:10px;
            }
            p {
                border-bottom:1px solid #B7DDF2;
                color:#666666;
                font-size:12px;
                margin-bottom:20px;
                padding-bottom:10px;
            }
            span {
                color:#666666;
                font-size:12px;
                margin-bottom:1px;
                
            }
            .btn{
            padding: 4px 12px;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            font-size: 14px;
            line-height: 20px;
            color: #333333;
            text-align: center;
            text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
            vertical-align: middle;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            border: 1px solid #B7DDF2;
            
            }

            .btn:hover{
            color: #333333;
            background-color: #e6e6e6;
            }

            div.container {
                min-width: 980px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
            .header {
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            }
            body {
                font: 90%/1.45em "Helvetica Neue", HelveticaNeue, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                color: #333;
                background-color: #fff;
            }
            div.dt-button-collection {
                position: static;
            }
        </style>

        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.2/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.2/css/rowGroup.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
        <link rel ="stylsheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.3/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css"/>
        
        <div class ="container">
            <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                    <th>Program</th>
                    <th>Deliverable</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Approved</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Program</th>
                    <th>Deliverable</th>
                    <th>To</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Approved</th>
                    <th>Notes</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
            <form id="myform" type="post">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend align="center">Update Datatable</legend>
                    <p>Please fill out the shown fields to add data to the DataTable</p>
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="program">Program :</label>
                    <select name = "program" id="dProgram">
                            <option value = "AHR">AHR</option>
                            <option value = "AMMO">AMMO</option>
                            <option value = "DAR-Q">DAR-Q</option>
                            <option value = "Doctrine Development">Doctrine Development</option>
                            <option value = "Operational Energy">Operational Energy</option>
                            <option value = "Ordnance Multimedia">Ordnance Multimedia</option>
                            <option value = "SRC Handbook">SRC Handbook</option>
                            <option value = "WTBn">WTBn</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Deliverable">Deliverable :</label>
                    <select name="Deliverable" id="dDeliverable">
                            <option value = "Meeting Minutes">Meeting Minutes</option>
                            <option value = "Monthly Status Report (MSR)">Monthly Status Report (MSR)</option>
                            </select>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="To"> To:</label>
                    <input type="text" align= "center" id="dTo" name="to" placeholder="example@example.com">
                    </div>      
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Date">Date: </label>
                    <input type="date" align= "center" id="dDate" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"> 
                    </div>  
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Approved">Approved :</label>
                    <select name="Approved" id="dApproved">
                            <option value = "True">Yes</option>
                        <option value = "False">No</option></select>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="elements">
                    <label for="Notes"> Notes :</label>
                    <input type="text" align= "left" id="dNotes" name="notes" placeholder="Please provide notes">
                </div>
                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="btn" name="btn" class="btn" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                        var baseUrl = "http://webappurl";
                        function loadData() { //Initializing the AJAX Request function to load in the external list data from different subsites
                            //create an array of urls to run through the ajax request instead of having to do multiple AJAX Requests
                            var urls = [baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AMMO Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes", 
                            "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Dar-Q Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes", 
                            "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('WTBn Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
                            "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ODMultiDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
                            "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('OEDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
                            "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('DocDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
                            "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AHRDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable",
                            "baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('SRCDeliverables')/items?$select=Program,To,Date,Approved,Notes,Deliverable"];
                            
                            for (i=0; i < urls.length; i++) { //for loop to run through the AJAX until all URLs have been reached
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: urls[i],
                                    method: "GET",
                                    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                                    success: function (data) { // success function which will then execute "GETTING" the data to post it to a object array (data.value)
                                        console.log(data);
                                        if(data.d != null && data.d != undefined && data.d.results.length> 0){
                                            var table = $('#myTable').DataTable();
                                            table.rows.add(data.d.results).draw();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }); 
                            }
                        }

                        $(document).ready(function() {
                            var collapsedGroups = {}; 
                            var top = '';
                            var parent = '';
                            
                        var table = $('#myTable').DataTable( {
                            "columns": [
                            { "data": "Program", visible: false },
                            { "data": "Deliverable", visible: false },
                            { "data": "To" },
                            { "data": "Date" },
                            { "data": "Approved" },
                            { "data": "Notes" }
                            ],
                            
                            dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-10'f><'col-sm-12 col-md-2'B>>" +
                            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                            "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
                            buttons: [{
                            extend: 'collection',
                            className: "btn-dark",
                            text: 'Export',
                            buttons:
                            [{
                            extend: "excel", className: "btn-dark"
                            },
                            {
                            extend: "pdf", className: "btn-dark"
                            },
                            {
                            extend: "print", className: "btn-dark"   
                            },
                            ],
                            }],
                            order: [[0, 'asc'], [1, 'asc'] ],   
                            rowGroup: {
                                    dataSrc: [
                                    'Program',
                                    'Deliverable'
                                    ],
                                    startRender: function (rows,group,level){
                                        var all;
                                        if (level === 0) {
                                            top = group;
                                            all = group;
                                        } else if (level === 1) {
                                            parent = top + group; 
                                            all = parent; 
                                            // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                                            if (!collapsedGroups[top]) {
                                                return;
                                            }                   
                                        } else {
                                            // if parent collapsed, nothing to do
                                            if (!collapsedGroups[parent]) {
                                                return;
                                            } 
                                            all = top + parent + group;
                                        }

                                        var collapsed = !collapsedGroups[all];
                                        console.log('collapsed:', collapsed);
                                    
                                    rows.nodes().each(function(r) {
                                        r.style.display = collapsed ? 'none' : '';
                                    });
                                    //Add category name to the <tr>.
                                    return $('<tr/>')
                                        .append('<td colspan="8">' + group + ' (' + rows.count() + ')</td>')
                                        .attr('data-name', all)
                                        .toggleClass('collapsed', collapsed);
                                        
                                    
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                        } );
                            
                        loadData();

                        $('#myTable tbody').on('click', 'tr.dtrg-start', function () {
                                var name = $(this).data('name');
                                collapsedGroups[name] = !collapsedGroups[name];
                                table.draw(false);
                            });   

                            
                        });
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#btn").click(function(e){
                            var jsonData = {};
                            
                        var formData = $("#myform").serializeArray();
                        // console.log(formData);
                        
                        $.each(formData, function() {
                                if (jsonData[this.name]) {
                                if (!jsonData[this.name].push) {
                                    jsonData[this.name] = [jsonData[this.name]];
                                }
                                jsonData[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                            } else {
                                jsonData[this.name] = this.value || '';
                            }
                                
                            
                        });
                        console.log(jsonData);
                            $.ajax({  
                                    async: true, // Async by default is set to “true” load the script asynchronously  
                                    // URL to post data into sharepoint list  or your own url
                                    url: baseUrl + "_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AMMO Deliverables')/items?$select=Program,Deliverable,To,Date,Approved,Notes",  
                                    method: "POST", //Specifies the operation to create the list item  
                                    data: JSON.stringify({  
                                        '__metadata': {  
                                            'type': 'SP.Data.AMMO_x0020_DeliverablesListItem' // it defines the ListEnitityTypeName  
                                        },  
                                    //Pass the parameters
                                        'Program': $("#dProgram").val(),  
                                        'Deliverable':$("#dDeliverable").val(),  
                                        'To': $("#dTo").val(),  
                                        'Date': $("#dDate").val(),  
                                        'Approved': $("#dApproved").val(),  
                                        'Notes': $("#dNotes").val()            
                                    }),  
                                    headers: {  
                                        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the Data format   
                                        "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose", //It defines the content type as JSON  
                                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val() //It gets the digest value   
                                    },  
                                    success: function(data) {  
                                        alert("Item created successfully", "success"); // Used sweet alert for success message  
                                    },  
                                    error: function(error) {  
                                        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));  
                            
                                    }  
                            
                                })  
                            });
                        });
            </script>

        </div>
```

Comment: I updated my code to be similar to this, and It doesn't work nor does it show any errors in the log

Comment: Also, you dont have the form in a div/DataTable button like myself. Could that be casuing the issue

Comment: Oh boy oh boy. You copied mine and you changed your Date column to Date1 and Notes to Notes1. Its becuase we do have same name columns already in out Tenant. Let me edit your script

Comment: I tried fixing it, and it still wont send to the list to repopulate to the table. It also screws up my children/parent rows

Comment: Just made the adjustments, and it still doesn't work. It still screws up my child rows for the program under deliverable. They are no longer grouped together

Comment: Don't worry. Updated my script according to your lists and column names. Just copy the whole script and replaced snippit in your script editor webpart. Thats all

Comment: still not same as i updated my script with most recent code. Copy all in My Script Editor Code section: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63926980/5313155

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221594/discussion-between-ali-raza-zafar-and-bigchungus).

Answer (score -3):

You do not need to much of script, best way to submit form by onsubmit method using return false. You can use Jquery post method for this.

Comment: This isn't an answer